# Order By Having Certain Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Need a Select Query for the following scenario, using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

```
Order Customer Order_Type
1     A        NULL
2     A        NULL
3     B        S
4     C        NULL
5     D        S
6     B        NULL
```

I want to Group Customer who have placed Order Type S, So the output I am expecting is

```
Order Customer Order_Type
3     B        S
6     B        NULL
5     D        S
1     A        NULL
2     A        NULL
4     C        NULL

SELECT Order, Customer, Order_Type FROM CustomerOrder GROUP BY Customer,Order, Order_Type HAVING {?}
```

Comment: Right.. that is not a GROUP BY that is an ORDER BY. Switch the wording around in the question. It's an interesting question though.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? sql-server, mysql, postgresql, Teradata? If you could also please add that as a tag as it will probably have some bearing on the answer since there are some windowing functions that might help here.

Comment: when you use `GROUP BY` clause, it must contain the list of columns, that are used in the `SELECT` clause without aggregation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT *
FROM CustomerOrder      
ORDER BY COUNT(CASE WHEN Order_Type = 'S' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer) DESC, 
         Customer
```

I assume you basically want to order your data, placing on top groups of customers having at least one 'S'.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/281d0/1)

**Edit:** You have to add:

```
CASE WHEN Order_Type = 'S' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

at the tail of the `ORDER BY` clause if you want to always place `'S'` records in the first place of their group.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/82e73/1)

Comment: I don't know about the performance, but this seems to be simpler than others

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` is for grouping multiple rows together into a single row, based on a common column value.

For instance, you might get a count of how many orders a particular customer has made like so:

```
SELECT Customer, COUNT(*) FROM Table
GROUP BY Customer
```

That would get you output listing the customer name and the number of order rows they had.

If you want to limit this (like a `WHERE` clause), you use `HAVING`.

```
SELECT Customer, COUNT(*) FROM Table
GROUP BY Customer
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

This will get you all the Customers who have more than 1 order.

If you want to organize your output, you can sort using `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT * FROM Table
ORDER BY Order_Type
```

You can even use multiple columns to sort by.  It will first sort based on the first column, and then it will sort those groups (rows whose first column all match) by the second, and so on.

```
SELECT * FROM Table
ORDER BY Order_Type, Customer
```

EDIT:

With other answers, it has become clear to me what you're really asking.  I'll leave my answer above as-is, because a basic explanation of GROUP and ORDER is potentially useful to people who might find this question in the future.

As others have said, if you wish to organize your table such that all customers who have any row that fits criteria X (in this case, 'Order_Type=S'), you can't do it with a simple query or a HAVING clause.  As is pointed out, there are numerous ways to do this.

Comment: None of these will give OP the result they were looking for though.

Comment: Still Doesn't have anything which would group by Customer who have placed atleast one Order of type S, Problem is Having only works with aggregate function but not with a filter

Comment: @JNevill: OP's desired result in the question doesn't match what their text says.  With a question this confused, I tried to give an answer that touches on what they asked and answers what they really seemed to want/need.

Comment: But they posted expected results.

Comment: @JNevill: Yes, they did.  And their table of expected results didn't match what the text said, which was confusing for me (and many others, based on other answers and comments).  With other answers, I see the actual question now: "I want to organize this so that people who meet criteria 'X' are at the top, followed by those without 'X'."  That wasn't clear in the question itself.  I'm editing now to better reflect the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is an `ORDER BY`, not a `GROUP BY`.

Try this:

```
SELECT
t.[Order],
t.Customer,
t.Order_Type
FROM
t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Customer FROM t WHERE Order_Type = 'S') s
ON t.Customer = s.Customer
ORDER BY
s.Customer DESC
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a902e/4/0)

What we do here, is simply to add the information, if each customer has an order of order_type `S`. With the `LEFT JOIN` this customer number is either the customer number if he has, or `NULL`. So we order `DESC`ending, and then by whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to produce the result you're looking for:

```
declare @t table ([Order] int,Customer char(1),Order_Type char(1))
insert into @t([Order],Customer,Order_Type) values
(1,'A',NULL),
(2,'A',NULL),
(3,'B','S' ),
(4,'C',NULL),
(5,'D','S' ),
(6,'B',NULL)

;With TypeS as (
    select *, --TODO - Column list
     MAX(CASE WHEN Order_Type = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     OVER (PARTITION BY Customer) as SeenS
    from @t
)
select * --TODO - Explicit column list if SeenS shouldn't appear
from TypeS ORDER BY SeenS desc,Customer,[Order]
```

We use a window function `MAX(...) OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` in order to work out, on each row, whether *any* row for that customer has an `S` order type.

Results:

```
Order       Customer Order_Type SeenS
----------- -------- ---------- -----------
3           B        S          1
6           B        NULL       1
5           D        S          1
1           A        NULL       0
2           A        NULL       0
4           C        NULL       0
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use temporary table:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_1 AS (
SELECT
   *
FROM CustomerOrder
WHERE Order_Type is not null
ORDER BY Order_Type DESC
);

SELECT t1.* FROM CustomerOrder t1
LEFT JOIN tmp_1 t2 ON t2.Customer = t1.Customer
```